# Is it possible to nest GridViews in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, nested

I am wondering if it is possible to nest GridView's like this?

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> 
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvNCReports" runat="server" Width="100%" BackColor="White" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="false" RowStyle-BorderColor="DarkGray" 
             BorderWidth="1">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
                 <Columns>
                     <asp:BoundField DataField="assessmentName" 
                         HeaderText="Assessment Name" 
                         SortExpression="assessmentName" /> 
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                         <asp:GridView ID="gvNClinks" runat="server" Width="100%" 
                             BackColor="White" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                             RowStyle-BorderColor="DarkGray" BorderWidth="1">
                             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="LightGray" />
                             <Columns> </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
                 </asp:TemplateField>             
             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:Panel>
```

I am new to web form, so any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is a good writeup here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533165/a-nested-gridview-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just have to bind the inner using a OnRowDataBound for the outer, and otherwise it's entirely possible.

While I don't like it, I've been known to do it myself. I recommend, instead, doing a set of nested repeaters, as the markup is generally simpler, but requires a tad more HTML on your end.

Comment: bear in mind that this is a nasty way to present data. I can think of at least four other ways I would prefer to do it, including loading the data as JSON and letting some jQuery on the page load it into the grid using templates. That way, as convoluted as it may sound, is to me the better idea

Comment: could you hinton four other ways? a jquery / javascript table is one method i can imagine. just to know :)

Comment: Thanks , the repeaters seem like a simple solution. I am going to give the JSON method a shot , seems more elegant.

Comment: @Naveen ~ Make a handler that returns JSON for the data and load the page, then asynchronously load the data for the subgrids as you need it, and start with them hidden. It will be loads faster. You can use jQuery to help with the templating, and of course the built in cross-browser-ajax support.