# A nested gridview example

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have been searching for more than one day for a way to create a nested gridview that can be added to a C# windows form. I have found many examples that are using ASP.NET however I couldn't find any that are done with C#. I would like a master/detail Gridview that looks like the one in the following link:
http://ilovedeveloper.blogspot.com/2009/05/nested-gridview-using-c.html

Comment: [ExtGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12299/ExtGridView) may be of interest, I haven't used it but I believe it's in C#.

Comment: What I am actually after is to create a master/detail GridView purely in C#. I want to use this control in a windows form.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 21):

**IMAGE**

[image: Your requirement]

**.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CS.aspx.cs" Inherits="CS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        .Grid td
        {
            background-color: #A1DCF2;
            color: black;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height:200%
        }
        .Grid th
        {
            background-color: #3AC0F2;
            color: White;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height:200%
        }
        .ChildGrid td
        {
            background-color: #eee !important;
            color: black;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height:200%
        }
        .ChildGrid th
        {
            background-color: #6C6C6C !important;
            color: White;
            font-size: 10pt;
            line-height:200%
        }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid"
        DataKeyNames="CustomerID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="images/plus.png" />
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="Order Id" />
                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="OrderDate" HeaderText="Date" />
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name" />
            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvCustomers.DataSource = GetData("select top 10 * from Customers");
            gvCustomers.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private static DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string customerId = gvCustomers.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("gvOrders") as GridView;
            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select top 3 * from Orders where CustomerId='{0}'", customerId));
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LOL Sasidharan!  I guess you're getting downvotes because you don't read the OP's question very carefully.  OP has clearly mentioned that OP is specifically looking for WindowsForm grid and not ASP.Net!.  hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is a good solution, however issues reside in its inability to load sub-rows at run-time and requires all data to be loaded into memory at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
BindGridview();
}
}
// This method is used to bind gridview from database
protected void BindGridview()
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select TOP 4 CountryId,CountryName from Country", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
gvParentGrid.DataSource = ds;
gvParentGrid.DataBind();

}
protected void gvUserInfo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
con.Open();
GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("gvChildGrid");
int CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[1].Text);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from State where CountryID=" + CountryId, con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
con.Close();
gv.DataSource = ds;
gv.DataBind();
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. Please add some explanation to your answer. Without any explanation it is unclear whether your post should be an answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the template column to create nested gridview, you need to build HTML table inside the template column in first row of column is fill with main grid rows using custom binding using row databound event. you shod add nest grid view inside the second row of the html table

check with following link..
http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/multilevel-nested-gridview-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1012.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have many resources who provides this :

[Walkthrough: Creating a Nested GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992038%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[Nested GridView Example in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

[Gridview inside Gridview in ASP.NET C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189997/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-asp-net-Csharp)

[Nested gridview c# (Google search)](https://www.google.fr/search?q=nested%20gridview%20asp.net&rlz=1C1CHFX_frFR527FR527&oq=nested%20gridview%20asp.net&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.5209j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#psj=1&q=nested%20gridview%20c#)

Comment: What I am actually after is to create a master/detail GridView purely in C#. I want to use this control in a windows form.

Answer (score 0):

Updated jquery using .on instead of .live

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "[src*=plus]", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
        $(this).attr("src", "../../_Images/minus.png");
    });
    $(document).on("click", "[src*=minus]", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "../../_Images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```